# Phonegap - iOS statusbar plug-in - acting weard in landscape

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad

I try to use the status bar plug-in in the config.xml to build with phonegap

and then change the color and StatusBarOverlaysWebView, ...

Everything's fine when opening the app in portrait. Statusbar in black above the appview and it remains OK when changing to landscape.
But opening the app in landscape gives me 3/4 of the screen (from the left) in black. If I change to portrait from there, the black remains.

Anyone else had this problem? 
changing the phonegap version doesn't help

thnx
grtz

Answer (score 0):

Change the plugin with this one:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" />
```